firebase callable function does not work if called from the app, but it does from the shell
I have a callable function that woks as expected when I call it with the firebase shell, but when called from the app it crashes with this error:
ERROR 2024-09-27T16:26:24.811848Z Unhandled error FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app does not exist. 
Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.

this is my  function:
exports.addCustomClaim = onCall({secrets: [privateKey], ...params},
  async (data: any)=>{
      console.log("data", data.data);
    const privateKey= defineSecret("PRIVATE_KEY");
    const clientEmail = defineString("CLIENT_EMAIL");
    const projectId = defineString("PROJECT_ID");
    const databaseURL = defineString("DATABASE_URL");
    if(admin.apps.length===0){
      console.log("no app");
      try {
        console.log("trying to initialize");
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert({
          privateKey: privateKey.value().replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
          projectId: projectId.value(),
          clientEmail: clientEmail.value(),
        }),
        databaseURL: databaseURL.value(),
      });
    }
  catch (error) {
    console.error("errore:",error);
    return error;
  }
  }
  else {
console.log("app already initialized", admin.apps.length)
  }
      const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.data.email);
    try {
        await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, data.data.claims);
        if (data.data.logoutUser) {
            console.log("logging out user", user.uid);
            await admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(user.uid);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
        return {error: err, user: user.uid, data};
    }

});

this is how I call it:
const functions = getFunctions()
    const addCustomClaim = httpsCallable(functions, 'addCustomClaim')
    return addCustomClaim({ email, claims })


This has nothing do with the function itself.  The error message is telling you what went wrong.  Did you call initializeApp before trying to invoke the function?  The error message suggests you did not.

Did you try Doug's suggestion? Does it solve the problem?

If I invoke the function from the firebase shell it works, then  initializeApp ia called, but  when I invoke  the function  from the app  it crashs, it seems strange to me, I am  sure I am forgoting something, it should work in both the cases or not working at all

Yes I checked: inizitializeApp is the first think I invoke after having checked  admin.apps.length ==0, so I still do not understand why I get this error

At the end I found the solution admin should be initialized with admin.initializeApp, better if as global
